# Apache - Redirect while dropping everything after domain

Tags: apache-2.4, web-hosting

So I can do a simple redirect on an Apache virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.old-domain.com
        Redirect / www.new-domain.com/new-resource

</VirtualHost>
```

But of course, if I go to `www.old-domain.com/old-resource` it redirects to `www.new-domain.com/new-resourceold-resource`. I'd like to just drop everything after the old domain name, regardless of the directory or file, so `www.old-domain.com/whatever/doesntmatter/foo.html` still just redirects to `www.new-domain.com/new-resource`.

How do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with a bit more searching it found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669077/how-to-redirect-all-traffic-to-apache-document-root) question, and it's a pretty simple solution:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.old-domain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule ^/?.+$ www.new-domain.com [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```